# Google Apps Scripts getFirstName and getGivenName error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working in Google Apps Script trying to pre-populate a field with the currently logged in users first name and last name.  According to Google's documentation I should be able to get this with [getGivenName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_domainuser#getGivenName) and [getFamilyName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_domainuser#getFamilyName).  When I include those using the following code:

```
  var myFirstName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getGivenName();
  var myLastName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getFamilyName();
```

I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function getGivenName in object
TypeError: Cannot find function getFamilyName in object
```

On the other hand, this code works:

```
var myEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var myUsername = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
```

Are these functions not yet implemented?

Answer (score 1):

The doc you refer to is about `UserManager` which is a part of the `Domain Service` only available with a Google Apps account in a domain... nothing to do with `Session.getEffectiveUser()` that is part of the [Base service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_session?hl=en).

You could use the autocomplete feature to avoid such confusion.

**EDIT : for info :** if the logged user is in your contacts, then you can retrieve whatever is in there.
Example code with comments:

```
function getUserInfo(){
   var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
   var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
Logger.log(email+'  '+userName)
   if(ContactsApp.getContact(email)){ ;// if the logged user is in your contacts
     var fullName = ContactsApp.getContact(email).getFullName();// there a quite a few parameters available from here
     var nickName = ContactsApp.getContact(email).getNickname();// these are just examples
     var tel =  ContactsApp.getContact(email).getPhones();// returns an array of phones object
     var telnums=[]
      for(var t in tel){telnums.push(tel[t].getLabel()+"="+tel[t].getPhoneNumber())} ;// get the numbers ans store in an array
Logger.log(fullName+' / '+nickName+' / phone :'+telnums.join(' & ')) ;// join the array for proper display
   }
}
```

**EDIT 2 : following your comment :**
*FOR GOOGLE APPS ACCOUNT* , this code is working to get user information, see [doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_domainuser), you have to get the `user` object

```
function getUserInfo(){
   var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
   var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
Logger.log(email+'  '+userName)
   var user = UserManager.getUser(userName);// get the user object
   var firstName = user.getGivenName();// from there get whatever you want that is available (see autocomplete, not so much possibilities...)
   var familyName = user.getFamilyName();
  Logger.log(firstName+' / '+familyName)
}
```

Note : before using this script you have to authorize this API :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I should have been more specific, this script will be used in a Google Apps for Education domain.If Session.getEffectiveUser() isn't what I should be using, what can I use to get the first and last name of the person currently running the script?

Comment: see also note on provisioning and Email migration API that has to be enabled for your domain.

Comment: There are alternatives,please post a new thread on this rather than commenting. Thx